# Generate table with merged cells

Tags: php, html, loops, html-table

I need some help with tables.

I've got some example data:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'ID' => string '1' (length=1)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'Name' => string 'Jon' (length=3)
      1 => string 'Jon' (length=3)
      'SecondName' => string 'Dee' (length=3)
      2 => string 'Dee' (length=3)
      'Date' => string '3, 2011' (length=7)
      3 => string '3, 2011' (length=7)
      'TotalHours' => string '06:48' (length=5)
      4 => string '06:48' (length=5)
      'TotalFee' => string '124' (length=3)
      5 => string '124' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array
      'ID' => string '3' (length=1)
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      'Name' => string 'Some ' (length=5)
      1 => string 'Some ' (length=5)
      'SecondName' => string 'Preson' (length=6)
      2 => string 'Preson' (length=6)
      'Date' => string '3, 2011' (length=7)
      3 => string '3, 2011' (length=7)
      'TotalHours' => string '32:06' (length=5)
      4 => string '32:06' (length=5)
      'TotalFee' => string '436' (length=3)
      5 => string '436' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array
      'ID' => string '3' (length=1)
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      'Name' => string 'Some ' (length=5)
      1 => string 'Some ' (length=5)
      'SecondName' => string 'Preson' (length=6)
      2 => string 'Preson' (length=6)
      'Date' => string '4, 2011' (length=7)
      3 => string '4, 2011' (length=7)
      'TotalHours' => string '10:00' (length=5)
      4 => string '10:00' (length=5)
      'TotalFee' => string '1345' (length=4)
      5 => string '1345' (length=4)
```

Now I'm trying to dynamically create html table with this data grouped by person, so Name/Second name wont repeat in every row. Is it possible to merge Name cells?

```
/-----------------------------------------\
|          | month 1 |  hours  |   cash   |
| Person 1 |------------------------------|
|          | month 2 |  hours  |   cash   |
|-----------------------------------------|
| Person 2 | month 1 |  hours  |   cash   |
\-----------------------------------------/
```

etc...
Is it possible?

Comment: In the resulting HTML or in your array?

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for is a `rowspan`.
Check out this link: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html

Usage:

```
<TABLE BORDER=2 CELLPADDING=4>
<TR>
    <TH ROWSPAN=3 BGCOLOR="#99CCFF">Production</TH>
    <TD>Raha Mutisya</TD> <TD>1493</TD>
    </TR>
<TR>
    <TD>Shalom Buraka</TD> <TD>3829</TD> 
    </TR>
<TR>
    <TD>Brandy Davis</TD> <TD>0283</TD>
    </TR>
<TR>
    <TH ROWSPAN=3 BGCOLOR="#99CCFF">Sales</TH>
    <TD>Claire Horne</TD> <TD>4827</TD>
    </TR>
<TR>
    <TD>Bruce Eckel</TD> <TD>7246</TD>
    </TR>
<TR>
    <TD>Danny Zeman</TD> <TD>5689</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>

</TABLE></html>
```

You need to add this properly ofcourse, but it gives you the basic idea.

Also you need to order the results by the person's name (or ID) and keep track if it changes when running through the resultset. That's the easiest solution.